# Can you Golf Golf?

Tags: code-golf, number, random

You are required to generate a random 18-hole golf course.

Example output:

```
[3 4 3 5 5 4 4 4 5 3 3 4 4 3 4 5 5 4]
```

Rules:

- Your program must output a list of hole lengths for exactly 18 holes
- Each hole must have a length of 3, 4 or 5
- The hole lengths must add up to 72 for the entire course
- Your program must be able to produce every possible hole configuration with some non-zero-probability (the probabilities of each configuration need not be equal, but feel free to claim extra kudos if this is the case)

Comment: Please confirm, 44152809 solutions?

Comment: I too am curious on the exact number of solutions, however I think it should be more than 44 million... (I am no mathmetician, however: |
1(5)/1(3) = 306 possibilities (17*18) |
2(5)/2(3) = 69360 poss (17*17*16*15) |
3(5)/3(3) = 11182080 poss (16*16*16*15*14*13) |
does that look right?

Comment: @baby-rabbit: I can confirm 44,152,809 solutions by brute force enumeration.  Also, it can be directly calculated this way: since the average is exactly `4`, and the only possibilities are `3`, `4`, or `5`, the possible solution classes are { `no 3's or 5's`, `one 3 and one 5`, `two 3's and two 5's`, ..., `nine 3's and nine 5's` }.  This can be calculated by `nCr(18,0)*nCr(18,0) + nCr(18,1)*nCr(17,1) + nCr(18,2)*nCr(16,2) + ... + nCr(18,9)*nCr(9,9) = 44,152,809`.  This means approximately `11.4%` of all possible combinations are valid solutions `(44,152,809 / 3^18)`.

Comment: `sum(factorial(18)/factorial(x)/factorial(y)/factorial(z) for x in range(25) for y in range(25) for z in range(25) if 3*x+4*y+5*z == 72 and x+y+z == 18)` gives `44152809L`

Answer (score 29):

## k (<s>18 17</s> 16 chars)

Back to the original approach, credit to CS for the improvement.

```
(+/4-){3+18?3}/0
```

Other approach (17 chars), same method as the J solution, H/T to CS

```
4+a,-a:9?2 -18?18
```

<s>Old version:</s>

```
(72-+/){18?3+!3}/0
```

Not susceptible to stack-overflow and runs in fixed amount of space.

Comment: What's H/T to CS?

Comment: Hat-tip, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hat_tip#Metaphor

Comment: This program helped me discover [a bug](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok/commit/90fd759d9d2a829a7aee3554776cbb822e9e9c45) in my K interpreter- thanks! I didn't previously realize that nilads could be applied to a single argument (which they ignore).

Answer (score 17):

## K, 28

```
{$[72=+/s:18?3 4 5;s;.z.s`]}
```

Answer (score 15):

### J, <strike>20</strike> <strike>18</strike> 17 characters

```
(?~18){4+(,-)?9#2
```

This works in the same way as the previous answer except that the 9 random digits are either 0 or 1 and are negated before being appended. This means there are as many `-1`s as there are `1`s. Adding 4 gives me a list of `3`s, `4`s and `5`s that add up to 72 every time.

Previous answer:

```
({~?~@#)3+(,2-])?9#3
```

Generates the first 9 holes randomly `?9#3`, then copies and inverts them `(,2-])` (turns a 3 into a 5 and a 5 into a 3) to generate the final 9. This guarantees that the total will be 72 (since every 3 will have a matching 5 the average total per hole will be 4 and 4x18=72). It then randomly shuffles the result `({~?~@#)` to ensure that every combination is possible.

Comment: actually you won't generate {3,5,4,4,4...} you are better off shuffling the entire result

Comment: @rachetfreak Good point. I'll edit now.

Answer (score 13):

## Mathematica <strike>71 68 66</strike> 60

With 6 chars saved by Tally's suggestion.

```
RandomSample@RandomChoice@IntegerPartitions[72, {18}, {3, 4, 5}]
```

> {5, 4, 3, 3, 5, 3, 5, 5, 3, 3, 4, 5, 3, 5, 4, 4, 5, 3}

All possible outcomes are possible, but they are not equally likely.

---

**Analysis**

```
IntegerPartitions[72, {18}, {3, 4, 5}]
```

produces all 10 possible partitions (combinations, not permutations) of 72 into 18 elements consisting of 3's, 4's and 5's.

[image: partitions]

---

`RandomChoice` selects one of those.

`RandomSample` returns a permutation of that choice.

Comment: Hehe, I was just about to post almost the exact same answer, only using RandomChoice instead of RandomInteger.
I think you can shave of 4 more characters by doing so.

Comment: Tally, thanks.  Your suggestion was helpful.

Answer (score 13):

### 16-bit x86 machine code under MS-DOS - 45 bytes

Hexdump:

```
0E5F576A12595188ECE44088C3E44130D8240374F400C4AAE2EF595E80FC2475DFAC0432CD29B020CD29E2F5C3
```

Base64 coded binary:

```
Dl9XahJZUYjs5ECIw+RBMNgkA3T0AMSq4u9ZXoD8JHXfrAQyzSmwIM0p4vXD
```

Actual source code with some comments:

```
 bits 16
 org 0x100

again:
 push cs               ; Save whatever CS we get.
 pop di                ; Use CS:DI as our course buffer..
 push di               ; Save for later use in the print loop
 push 18               ; We need 18 holes for our golf course.
 pop cx                ; ch = 0, cl = 18.
 push cx               ; Save for later use.
 mov ah, ch            ; Zero out ah.
generate_course:
 in al, 0x40           ; Port 0x40 is the 8253 PIT Counter 0.
 mov bl, al            ; Save the first "random" value in bl.
 in al, 0x41           ; Port 0x41 is the 8253 PIT Counter 1.
 xor al, bl            ; Add some more pseudo randomness.
 and al, 3             ; We only need the two lower bits.
 jz generate_course    ; If zero, re-generate a value, since we need only 3, 4, 5 holes.
 add ah, al            ; Sum in ah register.
 stosb                 ; Store in the course buffer.
 loop generate_course  ; Loop for 18 holes.
 pop cx                ; cx = 18.
 pop si                ; si = course buffer.
 cmp ah, 36            ; 72 holes?
 jne again             ; No, re-generate the whole course.

print:                 ; Yup, we have a nice course.
 lodsb                 ; Load the next hole.
 add al, '2'           ; Add ASCII '2' to get '3', '4' or '5'
 int 0x29              ; Undocumented MS-DOS print function.
 mov al, ' '           ; Print a space too for better readability.
 int 0x29              ; Print the character.
 loop print            ; Print the whole course.
 ret                   ; Return to the beginning of the PSP where a INT 0x20 happen to be.
```

Compile with `nasm 18h.asm -o 18h.com` and run under MS-DOS (or Dosbox), or NTVDM from a 32-bit Windows version.

Sample output:

```
4 5 4 5 4 5 3 4 3 4 3 4 4 5 4 3 5 3
```

Comment: love assembler...

Answer (score 8):

### R - 41

```
x=0;while(sum(x)!=72)x=sample(3:5,18,T);x

# [1] 5 3 5 3 3 3 3 3 5 4 5 4 5 4 4 5 5 3
```

The algorithm is similar to @sgrieve's.

Comment: Same problem as @sgrieve above -- nothing prevents it from going over in 18 holes.

Comment: That's not a problem, the sample command in this case always generates 18 values.

Answer (score 8):

## JavaScript, <s>66</s> <s>64</s> 61 chars

Heavily inspired by TwoScoopsofPig (PHP) and Joe Tuskan (JS).

```js
for(a=[s=0];s!=72;)for(s=i=0;i<18;s+=a[i++]=Math.random()*3+3|0);a
```

```js
for(a=[s=0];s-72;)for(s=i=0;i<18;s+=a[i++]=Math.random()*3+3|0)a
```

```js
for(a=s=[];s;)for(i=18,s=72;i;s-=a[--i]=Math.random()*3+3|0)a
```

Comment: `s!=72` can be `s-72` to save one char. And the last semi-colon `;a` isn't needed either for another char.

Comment: i never saw `for(i=x;i;i--)` before it saves 2 chars from `for(i=0;i<x;i++)`, thanks man!

Answer (score 8):

### GolfScript (26 chars)

```
{;0{3rand.3+@@+(}18*])}do`
```

There are some obvious similarities with Ilmari's solution, but also some obvious differences. In particular, I'm exploiting the fact that the average par is 4.

Comment: Damn, but that sure is a clever trick with the loop condition there.  I came up with  `{;0{3.rand+.@+}18*])72-}do` myself, but couldn't figure out how to get it any shorter from there. +1.

Answer (score 7):

## Python 77

**Code**

```
from numpy.random import*;l=[]
while sum(l)!=72:l=randint(3,6,18)
print l
```

**Output**

```
[3 4 4 5 3 3 3 5 4 4 5 4 5 3 4 4 5 4]
```

The import really kills this solution. It uses numpy to generate a 18 numbers between 3 and 5 and keeps generating lists until the sum of the list equals 72.

Comment: What prevents the program from reaching 72 well before generating 18 holes? What prevents it from skipping 72?

Comment: The code will always generate 18 holes, then check if the sum equals 72. For example, if the sum after 16 holes was 72, it would still generate another 2 holes, therby pushing the sum above 72 and failing the test.

Answer (score 7):

### GolfScript, 27 chars

```
{;18{3.rand+}*].{+}*72-}do`
```

Uses the same rejection sampling method as sgrieve's Python solution.  Thus, every valid output actually is equally likely.

Answer (score 7):

## Python 2, 70 bytes

```python
from random import*
print sample(([3,5]*randint(0,9)+[4]*99)[:18],18)
```

edit:

Here's another one, similar to the solution of sgrieve:

## Python 2, 73 bytes + equal probability

```python
from random import*
a=[]
while sum(a)-72:a=sample([3,4,5]*18,18)
print a
```

Answer (score 6):

### Q (25 characters)

Original (27)

```
while[72<>sum a:18?3 4 5];a
```

Sample output

```
4 4 3 3 4 5 4 3 4 5 5 3 5 5 5 4 3 3
```

Slightly shorter (25)

```
{72<>sum x}{x:18?3 4 5}/0
```

Answer (score 5):

**Python, <strike>128</strike> <strike>120</strike> 116 characters**

```python
import random,itertools
random.choice([g for g in itertools.product(*(range(3,6)for l in range(18))) if sum(g)==72])
```

*`import` statements are still length killers (23 characters only to import 2 function in the namespace)*

i hope you do not need the result in a near future, as this code first evaluates all possible solutions before chosing one at random. maybe the slowest solution to this problem.

i do claim extra kudos for equal probability of each configuration...

Comment: `import random,itertools`

Comment: you are right, that shorten things a bit.

Comment: Other tips: `import random as r,itertools as i` then use `r` and `i` instead of `random` and `itertools`. Use `18*[0]` instead of `range(18)`, and `[3,4,5,6]` instead of `range(3,6)` :)

Comment: i am using python 3: a list comprehension is a generator and has no length, which forbids its use with the `choice()` function. that's also what makes this code so slow...

Comment: Ah, I'm using 2.7. I've added my attempt at golfing your answer in my Q [here](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8464/3735)

Comment: Uh... in Python 3, list comprehensions produce lists and can be passed to `random.choice`. In fact, `[genexpr]` is syntactic sugar for `list(genexpr)`.

Comment: ooops, sorry, i messed up list comprehension and generator expression (i generally avoid list comprehension in favor of generator expression because of the better performance of iterator). so indeed, even in python3 i can still remove some characters... @Alex did it right.

Answer (score 4):

## Ruby 1.9 (62 chars)

```
a=Array.new(18){[3,4,5].sample}until(a||[]).inject(:+)==72
p a
```

## Rails (55 chars)

In the `$ rails c` REPL (in any Rails folder):

```
a=Array.new(18){[3,4,5].sample}until(a||[]).sum==72
p a
```

*Note: It works with Ruby 1.8 if you use `shuffle[0]` instead of `sample`.*

Comment: Do you need whitespace around until?

Comment: @Kaz You're right, it's not needed. :) 62 chars now.

Comment: You can use `(1..18).map{rand(3)+3}` to get the random array ;)

Answer (score 4):

## PHP - 77 Chars

```
<?while(array_sum($a)!=72){for($i=0;18>$i;){$a[++$i]=rand(3,5);}}print_r($a);
```

Much like sgrieve's solution, this builds a list of 18 holes, checks total par, and either prints it or rejects it and tries again. Oddly enough, our two solutions are the same length.

Rather annoyingly, PHP doesn't offer array functions with any brevity of name. Array_sum and print_r are killing me. Suggestions welcome.

Comment: Curly braces are not needed here, and sum can be `+=`. `<?while($s!=72)for($s=$i=0;18>$i;$s+=$a[++$i]=rand(3,5));print_r($a);`

Comment: That's useful - I never thought to put the logic _in_ the for loop call (and I feel kinda dumb for not incrementing a counter for the sum).

Comment: Thanks – but that isn't actually what I meant by "curly braces not needed"; you could have removed them in the original code too: `while(array_sum($a)!=72)for($i=0;18>$i;)$a[++$i]=rand(3,5);`

Comment: Well except I run against a stricter php.ini than that because I'm golfing at work; it complains no end about braces being missing/mismatched. Normally I would have.

Comment: That's odd; 5.4.7 with E_ALL|E_STRICT never complains about missing `{}`'s (since PHP's syntax explicitly allows that).

Comment: I'm stuck on 5.3.2. So. That.

Answer (score 4):

## Lisp (<s>78</s> 69 chars)

<s>(do((c()(mapcar(lambda(x)(+ 3(random 3)))(make-list 18))))((=(apply'+ c)72)c))</s>

```
(do((c()(loop repeat 18 collect(+ 3(random 3)))))((=(apply'+ c)72)c))
```

It's rather similar to sgrieve's Python solution.

Start with c as NIL, check for a sum of 72, the `do` "increment function" for c generates a list of 18 numbers between 3 and 5, check for 72 again, lather, rinse, repeat.

It's refreshing to see `do` and `loop` nicely play golf together.

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript, <s>116</s> <s>99</s> 65 bytes

<s>`for(i=0,h=[];i<18;)h[i++]=5;while(h.reduce(function(a,b){return a+b})!=72){i=Math.random()*18|0;h[i]=[3,4,4][i%3]}h;`</s>

<s>`h=[0];while(h.reduce(function(a,b){return a+b})-72)for(i=0;i<18;h[i++]=[3,4,5][Math.random()*3|0])h`</s>

```js
while(i%18||(a=[i=s=0]),s+=a[i++]=Math.random()*3+3|0,s-72|i-18)a
```

Comment: When I run this in Chrome 21, I get `i is not defined`.

Answer (score 3):

### C (123 chars) - effort on efficiency

Pipe through wc and it will generate all 44152809 solutions within 10 seconds...

```
char s[19];g(d,t){int i;if(d--){for(i=51,t-=3;i<54;i++,t--)if(t>=3*d&&t<=5*d)s[d]=i,g(d,t);}else puts(s);}main(){g(18,72);}
```

Oh, well - didn't read the question properly - but given we're generating all solutions then picking a random one with equal probability is a scripting exercise :P

Answer (score 3):

## Clojure - 55

```
(shuffle(mapcat #([[4 4][3 5]%](rand-int 2))(range 9)))
```

Quite a fun trick.... exploits the mathematical structure of the problem that there must be exactly as many 3 par holes as 5 par holes.

Answer (score 3):

## Python 83

```
import random as r;x=[]
while sum(x)!=72:x=[r.randint(3,5) for i in 18*[0]]
print x
```

Like sgrieve's solution, but without numpy

**Golfing Adrien Plisson's solution:**
120->108 characters

```
import random as r,itertools as i
r.choice([g for g in i.product(*([3,4,5,6]for l in 18*[0]))if sum(g)==72])
```

## MATLAB 53

```
x=[];
while sum(x)~=72
x=3+floor(rand(1,18)*3);
end
x
```

**Output**:

> x =
>        4     3     4     4     4     4     5     4     4     3     4     4     3     5     3     5     4     5

Comment: Nice approach, but you can save 4 bytes by typing `randi([3,5],1,18)` instead of `3+floor(rand(1,18)*3)`

Answer (score 3):

## Java (61 chars)

```
while(s!=72)for(i=0,s=0;i<18;i++)s+=3+(int)(Math.random()*3);
```

Sample output:

```
5 4 3 4 5 3 4 4 3 5 4 4 4 4 3 4 4 5
```

Comment: I'm no Java expert, but shouldn't there be a declaration of s and i, and some kind of call to System#println(..)?

Comment: This is just a code snippet, not a program. And it actually looks very much like @JoeIbanez' C version.

Answer (score 3):

### CJam, <s>17</s> 14 bytes

CJam is newer than this challenge, but this is not the shortest answer anyway, so that doesn't really matter.

```
Z5]Amr*I4e]mrp
```

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/)

To maintain the total of 72, each `3` must be paired with `5`. So here is how it works:

```
Z5]            e# Push [3 5].
   Amr         e# Get a random number between 0 and 9.
      *        e# Repeat the [3 5] array that many times.
       I4e]    e# Pad the array to size 18 with 4s.
           mr  e# Shuffle the array.
             p e# Print it.
```

Answer (score 2):

## C (94 chars)

```
int h[18],s=0,i;
while(s!=72)for(i=s=0;i<18;s+=h[i++]=rand()%3+3);
while(i)printf("%d ",h[--i]);
```

The `s=0` on line 1 may not be required, because what are the chances an uninitialized int will equal 72?  I just don't like reading uninitialized values in straight C.  Also, this probably requires seeding the `rand()` function.

### output

```
3 3 3 4 5 5 3 3 4 5 5 4 3 4 5 5 5 3
```

Comment: So basically you're gonna loop through random strings of 18 numbers ranged 3 to 5 until one happens to equal 72? Good thing efficiency isn't a requisite.

Comment: @KeithS To be fair, that's what the majority of the answers to this question are doing.

Answer (score 2):

## TXR (99 chars)

```
@(bind g@(for((x(gen t(+ 3(rand 3))))y)(t)((pop x))(set y[x 0..18])(if(= [apply + y]72)(return y))))
```

This expression generates an infinite lazy list of random numbers from 3 to 5:

```
(gen t (+ 3(rand 3)))  ;; t means true: while t is true, generate.
```

The rest of the logic is a simple loop which checks whether the first 18 elements of this list add up to 72. If not, it pops an element off and tries again. The `for` loop contains an implicit block called `nil` and so `(return ...)` can be used to terminate the loop and return value.

Note that the 99 character length includes a terminating newline, which is required.

Comment: I put in a commit that allows the (t) to be replaced by (). :)

Answer (score 2):

## C# (143 non-whitespace):

```
()=>{
  var n=new Math.Random().Next(10);
  Enumerable.Range(1,18)
    .Select((x,i)=>i<n?3:i>=18-n?5:4)
    .OrderBy(x=>Guid.NewGuid())
    .ForEach(Console.Write);
}
```

Comment: `new Guid()` creates an empty GUID. To actually generate a unique GUID you need to call a static method `Guid.NewGuid`.

Comment: And you have two off-by-one errors (so to speak): the comparisons should be i<n and i>=18-n, not the other way around. And you could reduce the size by using a constant 3 instead of x-1 and 5 instead of x+1. And then you could replace Enumerable.Repeat by Enumerable.Range.

Comment: Edited; still 143 chars

Comment: There is no `Math.Random`, it's `System.Random`.

Comment: Another C# approach (143 chars): `var r=new Random();for(;;){var e=Enumerable.Range(1,18).Select(i=>r.Next(3,6)).ToList();if(e.Sum()==72){e.ForEach(i=>Console.Write(i));break;}}`

Answer (score 2):

### Bash shell script (65 chars)

```
shuf -e `for x in {0..8}
do echo $((r=RANDOM%3+3)) $((8-r))
done`
```

([shuf](//www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/shuf-invocation.html) comes from the GNU coreutils package. Also, thanks Gareth.)

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, <strike>104</strike> <strike>102</strike> 98 chars.

```
import System.Random
q l|sum l==72=print l|1>0=main
main=mapM(\_->randomRIO(3::Int,5))[1..18]>>=q
```

Comment: `[1..n]>>[r]` is slightly shorter than `replicate n$r`.

Comment: Also changed `sequence` to `mapM`.

Answer (score 2):

### Perl, 74

```
{@c=map{3+int rand 3}(0)x18;$s=0;$s+=$_ for@c;redo unless$s==72}print"@c"
```

Alternative solution:

```
@q=((3,5)x($a=int rand 9),(4,4)x(9-$a));%t=map{(rand,$_)}(0..17);print"@q[@t{sort keys%t}]"
```

Answer (score 2):

### VBA - 117

VBA never wins at golf. :-)

```
Sub a()
Do Until d=72
d=0
c=""
For b=1 To 18
e=Int(3*Rnd()+3)
c=c &" " &e
d=d+e
Next
Loop
MsgBox c
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

### APL 12

```
4+{⍵,-⍵}?9⍴2
```

Note that I have the index origin set to 0, meaning arrays start at 0.  You can set this with `⎕IO←0`.

Comment: The question asks a program that can produce every possible configuration. Yours can produce simmetric ones. You can't produce for example 555455555333333343, at least it seems so to me.

Answer (score 2):

## R, 42 bytes

```
a=0;while(sum(a)-72)a=sample(3:5,18,r=T);a
```

`sample`, by default, draws evenly among the possible values (here `3 4 5`). `r=T` stands for `replace=TRUE` and allows sample with replacement.

Answer (score 1):

## Python, 97

Using a different method than the rejection sampling, this picks a random list of indices of random even length and alternates adding and subtracting to the elements at these indices.

```
from random import*;a=[4]*18;d=1
for i in sample(range(18),2*randint(0,9)):a[i]+=d;d=-d
print a
```

Answer (score 1):

## Clojure - 72 chars

`(some #(if(=(apply +%)72)%)(partition 18(repeatedly #(+(rand-int 3)3))))`

Would be much shorter if Clojure didn't have such flowery descriptive function names :-)

Answer (score 1):

## Groovy

**126 chars**

```
def a=[];while(1){(new Random().nextInt(3)!=1&&a.size()<17?a<<3<<5:a<<4);if(a.size()==18)break};Collections.shuffle(a);print a
```

... ooooh, what a waste of chars :)

**110 chars**

```
def a=[];while(a.size()<18){(new Random().next(2)>1&&a.size()<17?a<<3<<5:a<<4)};Collections.shuffle(a);print a
```

Answer (score 1):

**PowerShell - 59**

```
while(($x|measure -s).sum-ne72){$x=1..18|%{3..5|random}};$x
```

Answer (score 1):

### Perl, 59

```
@a=map{3+rand 3|0}1..18 while 72!=eval join'+',@a;print"@a"
```

Not a winner by any means and could probably be improved still...

[Array sum method stolen from perlmonks](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=17439).

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 45 chars

```
NestWhile[{3, 5}~RandomInteger~18 &, {}, Tr@# != 72 &]
```

Answer (score 1):

## Perl 6 (42 bytes)

```
my@a=roll 18,3..5 while 72!= [+] @a;say @a
```

Probably too long to be acceptable, but at least the solution does exist. `roll` rolls the dice containing 3, 4, and 5. This generates numbers until the sum is equal to 72. I believe it can generate any course with equal probability (in theory), but considering pseudo-random number generators, it probably doesn't.

Sample output:

```
~ $ perl6 -e 'my@a=roll 18,3..5 while 72!= [+] @a;say @a'
3 4 3 3 4 5 4 3 4 4 3 4 5 4 5 5 4 5
```

Answer (score 1):

## TI-BASIC, [13 bytes](http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/tokens)

```
3+3fPart(randIntNoRep(0,17)/3
```

Outputs list of 18 integers. Meets all specs and has equal probability for each case.

Comment: And yes, total is always 72 thanks to our handy 2-byte `randIntNoRep(`

Comment: This only produces lists with exactly 6 3's, 6 4's, and 6 5's.

Comment: "Each hole must have a length of 3, 4 or 5"

Comment: "Your program must be able to produce every possible hole configuration"-- so for example, 9 3s and 9 5s would be valid.

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 18 bytes

```
#Jm+3O3U18IqsJ72JB
```

### How it works:

```
#                    infinite loop
       U18           generate the list [0, 1, ..., 17]
  m    U18           map every value of this list to
   +3O3              a random number between 3 and 5
 Jm+3O3U18           and assign the resulting list to J
          I          if
           qsJ72     the sum of J == 72
                J    print J
                 B   and exit the loop
```

Answer (score 1):

## CJam, 31

[Language was created after the question was posted]

Shamelessly long for CJam. It's basically a brute-force solution that keeps trying random configurations until it finds one that adds to 72.

```
L{;L{3mr3+_U+:U;a+}I*U72=:U!}g`
```

Answer (score 1):

### Java: 389 bytes

Run by calling the `b()` function.

```java
import java.util.*;public class a{Random b=new Random();int[]b(){int[]c=new int[18];int d=0;for(int i=0;i<c.length;i++){int e=g(c.length-i,d);int f=h(c.length-i,d);c[i]=i(e,f);d=d+c[i];}
return c;}
int i(int j,int k){return b.nextInt((k-j)+1)+j;}
int g(int l,int m){int n=(l-1)*5;int o=72-m;int p=o-n;return p<3?3:p;}
int h(int q,int r){int s=(q-1)*3;int t=72-r;int u=t-s;return u>5?5:u;}}
```

Comment: whoever downvoted can explain?

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript, <s>148</s> 143 bytes

```js
t=[];d=0;while(d<18){q=t.reduce(function(a,b){return a+b},z=0);while(!z||q+z+13-d*5<0||q+z-d*3>21)z=3+3*Math.random()|0;t.push(z);d++}alert(t)
```

Answer (score 1):

### PARI/GP, 85 bytes

```
vecextract(Vec(partitions(72,[3,5],[18,18])[random(10)+1]),numtoperm(18,random(18!)))
```

This generates a random partition of 72 with 18 components ranging from 3 to 5. The probabilities are not uniform, from 1/10 for the all-4 vector to 1/171531360 for [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5] and its permutations.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 16 bytes

```
[18Lε3LÌΩ}DO₆·Q#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/2tDC59xWY5/DPedW1rr4P2pqO7Q9UPn/fwA)

Comment: `3LÌ18ãʒO72Q}Ω` (13 bytes) should work in theory, but obviously times out. But I like your current approach since it actually gives a result. :) You can save a byte by changing the `3LÌΩ` to `ƵõΩ`. (Unfortunately `žP` has a length of 20 and `žq`/`žr` have a length of 17 instead of 18, otherwise the `18L` could have been replaced as well.)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 14 bytes

```
{:ṁ4≠|18ƛ3 6r℅
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJ7OuG5gTTiiaB8MTjGmzMgNnLihIUiLCIiLCIiXQ==)

```
{              # While...
 :ṁ            # The mean of the current value
   4≠          # Isn't 4
     |         # Do...
      18ƛ      # Fill an array of 18 elements with...
         3 6r℅ # one of 3, 4, and 5.
```

Answer (score 0):

## Octave, 37 bytes

```
while sum(x=2+randi(3,1,18))-72;end;x
```

It seems straight forward, (and I guess it is), but there are a few nifty tricks in here. It's 16 bytes shorter than the MATLAB answer, and I think it's hard to golf any further.

In Octave, you can initialize a variable inside a function call, or inside the `while` statement as done here. So, by doing `sum(x=2+randi(3,1,18))` I manage to continuously shuffle a vector of 18 elements with values `[3,4,5]` until the sum is 72. Instead of checking if this equals 72, we can subtract 72, and check if that's a truthy or a falsey value. Any non-zero values are considered truthy, so it will only stop when the sum is 72.
In the end, the loop stops and the vector is printed.

Answer (score 0):

### Seriously, 32 bytes (noncompeting)

```
35k9Ju;)@nktd9-τ4nktW;lJ`\`np@WX
```

This language post-dates this challenge. Posted to prove the need for a shuffle command and perhaps a cons command. This uses the same solution as CJam roughly:

```
35k                                 Push [5,3]
   9Ju                              Push a random number n from 1 to 9
      ;)                            Save a copy of it for later use.
        @n                          Make n copies of [5,3]
          (9-τ                      Transform n -> 2*(9-n)
              4n                    Push that many 4's
                kt                  Compile all numbers into a list.
                  W         W       Until the list is empty:
                   ;lJ`\`np@        Pop a random element from it.
                             X      Discard empty list.
```

Answer (score 0):

## [AHK](https://autohotkey.com/), 76 bytes

```
Loop{
s=
t=0
Loop,18{
Random,r,3,5
s:=r " "s
t+=r
}
If t=72
Break
}
Send,%s%
```

It's of the style to just loop forever until it happens to generate a list that totals 72 strokes.